# Stuck on Finding Roots in a Field

Tags: abstract-algebra

So I'm working in the field $F_{5}[x]/(x^2+2)$, and I have to find the roots of $t^2+2$ here.

Before I start, note that when I write = it's in this field.

So I know that the roots have to be less than degree 2 because it has to be of a degree less than $(x^2+1)$.

I use the fact that an element in this field could be written as ax+b, so I let $t=ax+b$, so then $t^2+2=a^2x^2+2abx+b^2+2=3a^2+2abx+b^2+2=0$

Then I know that $t^2=-2=3$, so I have $3a^2+2abx+b^2=3$, so I know there could be no x variable, hence a or b is 0.  b must be 0 bcause 3 doesn't have a root in this field, so

$3a^2=3$ so then $a^2=1$, and this is where I get stuck.  Any help is appreciated thanks in advance

Comment: I think you mean $F_{5}[x]/(x^2+1)$. In this case, $x^2=-1$, not $3$.

Comment: no it's $x^2+2$, I just double checked it

Comment: In this case, $x$ is the root you seek, isn't it?

Comment: I suppose but I'm confused as how to reach that conclusion, is it blaytantly obvious from the work I did?

Comment: The whole point of the construction $F[x]/poly(x)$ is to get a field in which $poly(x) = 0$.

Comment: I seemed to have made this a lot harder than needed, thanks everyone

Answer (score 2):

$F_{5}[x]/(x^2+2)$ is the same as $F_{5}[u]$ with $u^2+2=0$, where $u$ is the class of $x$ in the quotient ring.

So, the roots of $t^2+2$ in that ring are $\pm u$.